# Aplicar o princípio da responsabilidade única nos métodos que utilizam subscribe

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Considere a seguinte classe:

```
export class TesteComponent {
    //...
    public onSubmit() {
        this.checkA();
    }

    private checkA(): void {
        this.service.checkA(value)
            .subscribe(response => {
                if(response) {
                    //regra de negócio
                    this.checkB();
                } else {
                    //error
                }
            });
    }

    private checkB(): void {
        this.service.checkB(value)
            .subscribe(response => {
                if(response) {
                    //regra de negócio
                    this.checkC();
                } else {
                    //error
                }
            });
    }

    private checkC(): void {
        this.service.checkC(value)
            .subscribe(response => {
                if(response) {
                    //regra de negócio
                    //fim
                } else {
                    //error
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Repare que os métodos `checkA`, `checkB` e `checkC` executam um serviço que retorna um `Obervable` (podemos constatar isso através do `.subscribe`) que por sua vez é responsável por consumir uma API REST (não está explícito, mas interessa saber apenas que o serviço é assíncrono).

A cadeia de eventos começa com o método `checkA` e quando é concluído executa o método `checkB`, que por sua vez executa o `checkC`.

A questão é que os 3 métodos possuem funções bem definidas, porém ao concluir a tarefa o método executa outro método que possui uma responsabilidade completamente diferente, ferindo o princípio da responsabilidade única.

Por exemplo, quando coloco um carro a funcionar, não espero que ele começe a acelerar sozinho depois de colocar o cinto de segurança; é basicamente isso que estou a fazer ao executar métodos com diferentes responsabilidades.

Penso que o certo seria existir um elemento controlador responsável por decidir qual fluxo seguir (tal como eu decido o que fazer a seguir após colocar o cinto de segurança), mas como cada método é assíncrono, não sei como resolver o problema com Angular 5.

**Como resolver esse problema**?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema criando uma função controladora, por exemplo:

```
export class TesteComponent {
    //...
    public onSubmit() {
        this.invokeChain('checkA');
    }

    private invokeChain(operation: string) {
        switch(operation) {
            case 'checkA':
                this.checkA(fakeParam).subscribe((response: boolean) => {
                    if(response) this.invokeChain('checkB');
                    else this.errorHandling();
                });
             break;

            case 'checkB':
                this.checkB(fakeParam).subscribe((response: boolean) => {
                    if(response) this.invokeChain('checkC');
                    else this.errorHandling();
                });
             break;

            case 'checkC':
                this.checkC(fakeParam).subscribe((response: boolean) => {
                    if(response) console.log('Fim');
                    else this.errorHandling();
                });
             break;
        }
    }

    private checkA(value: string): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.service.checkA(value)
            .map((response: boolean) => response);
    }

    private checkB(value: string): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.service.checkB(value)
            .map((response: boolean) => response);
    }

    private checkC(value: string): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.service.checkC(value)
            .map((response: boolean) => response);
    }
}
```

Os nomes utilizados são apenas para exemplo.

Não sei se existe uma outra solução ou algum padrão para resolver o problema, mas considero uma solução razoável pelos seguintes motivos:

- Melhora a leitura do código.
- Os métodos `checkA`, `checkB` e `checkC` passaram a ter uma única responsabilidade.
- Como os métodos referidos acima passaram a ter uma única responsabilidade, podem ser reaproveitados em outros casos.
- Os métodos não são responsáveis por invocar outro método, isso passou a ser responsabilidade do método `invokeChain`. Esse método é responsável por manipular o fluxo conforme a resposta do *request* anterior.